# TimeSeries NLP: Using ARIMA with CountVectorizer

Tags: scikit-learn, arima, countvectorizer

I'm practicing on the kaggle news headline dataset on the DJIA prices as exported from Yahoo Finance: https://www.kaggle.com/aaron7sun/stocknews#Combined_News_DJIA.csv

There are not many discussions on NLP with TimeSeries, I attempted using [this article's code](https://machinelearningmastery.com/make-sample-forecasts-arima-python/) using CountVectorizer() however unsuccessful. I was wondering if anyone has any resources or suggestions?

My code below based on headline in dataset above:

```
def modeller(vect, X_tr, y_tr, X_te):
    X_train_dtm = vect.fit_transform(X_tr.unstack())
    X_test_dtm = vect.fit_transform(X_te.unstack())
    X_tr_arima = [x for x in X_train_dtm]
    print('done with count vectorizer. now modelling.')
    model = ARIMA(X_tr_arima, order=(1,1,1))
    print('done modelling. now fitting')
    model_fit = model.fit(X_tr_arima, y_tr)
    y_hat = model.predict(x_te_arima)
    return y_hat

vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = X.iloc[0:100], X.iloc[100:X.shape[0]], y[0:100], y[100:len(y)]
modeller(vect, X_train, y_train, X_test)
```

Output (error from ARIMA line):

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I could fix it using this approach.
Try to change

```
from pmdarima.pipeline import Pipeline
```

to

```
from pmdarima.pipeline import Pipeline as arimaPip
```